# Graphics card crashing

Tags: graphics-card, desktop-computer

My computer has a vent on the back side that sometimes gets very loud and the only way to stop it from making so much noise is to touch it for a second so it slows down. Every time I touch the vent to stop it from spinning and make it quieter, my graphics card crashes... Why is this and how could I fix it?

P.s. The vent is not part of the graphics card

Card: ATI Radeon HD 6970 Sapphire Flex

Case: Cooler Master HAF

Motherboard: ASUS P6X58D Premium

Comment: Why don't you just replace the fan?

Comment: I am probbably going to do that, but I want to find out why the graphics card is crashing when a fan that has absolutely nothing to do with it is stopped, @Ramhound

Comment: It sounds like the card is lose.  I am not sure what you mean by the "card is crashing".

Comment: The screen goes dark for a second, I get a "display driver stopped working and has recovered" error, and I have to restart my computer because all I can do is move the mouse arround. And I have noticed that when I am playing a game and this happens I also get an error from the game that the grahpics card has been removed.

Comment: New fan, 2 quid/bucks/shekels. While you're in there, strip the graphics card & CPU fans & evict the dust bunnies.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to touch the fans for any reason. regardless if it's too loud. Did you check the fan on your graphics card? it might be causing it to over heat. check for blown capacitors on the card.

Comment: the graphics card does have a problem with its own fan, but it cools itself just fine, this only happens when the chasis fan is bumped or touched... sometimes the fan "bumps" itself somehow and my graphics card crashes again

Comment: That sounds weird. something by be shorting it. try shaking the tower to see if theres a screw in there.